# Define $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\lim_{z \to 0, z\in L} f(z)=0$ where $L $ is the set of all lines passing thourgh the origin.

Tags: real-analysis

> Define $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ as $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, x^4<y<x^2 \\0 \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$ Show that $\lim_{z \to 0, z\in L} f(z)=0$ where $L $ is the set of all lines passing thourgh the origin.

I have that $L = \{(x,mx) \mid x,m \in \mathbb{R} \}$ so $z$ is of the form $z=(x,mx)$, but how can I show that the limit is zero? I'm a bit confused with the problem. Any hints how can I show this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $x^{4}<mx<x^{2}$ then $m >0$ and $x >m$ or else $x<0, m<0$ and $-x >-m$or $|x| >|m|$.  So $f(x,mx)=0$ whenever $|x| <|m|$.

Comment: How does $x^{4}<mx<x^{2}$ imply that $m > 0$ and $x > m$? I have $$x^{4}<mx<x^{2} \implies x^3 < m <  x$$ but $x$ and $x^3$ can be negative so $m < 0$?

Comment: @Takashi You are right. I have corrected the answer.